# Block schema in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am novice and work with Visual Studio, .Net, C#.
Could you please help me with the following question:
If I already created a solution
 How can I create and view its block-schema in Visual Studio?
 I mean diagram showing iteraction between mthods and variables etc

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: The class diagram is not available in all editions of Visual Studio. As can be seen in the [product comparison for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison), under "Architecture and Modelling", it is only available on the Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean creating UML Class Diagrams from code then look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx

Also there is set of videos about modeling features of Visual Studio
http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/clinted

But architecture explorer feature is present only in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Also look at Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff655021.aspx

When you have no Ultimate version of VS, maybe [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) will be good free alternative for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project, "View class diagram". This is available only in Ultimate edition.

Comment: And if you don't have Ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds more like a "Sequence Diagram".  If you have Visual STudio 2010 Ultimate, you and right-click within any method and select "Generate Sequence Diagram".

But, sequence diagrams don't show all interactions with local variables; just method (and optionally property) invocations.